# MOD Rewrite query string redirect issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website xxxxx.com and the URL structure to dynamic content is
xxxxx.com/tours/index.php?tourid=x
where tour id is the key and x is the value

I've come up with this .htaccess rule that uses mod re-write to redirect traffic to the above URL to
xxxxx.com/x
where x is the value

Problem is:
When I go to the main URL ie. www.xxxxx.com/ or www.xxxxx.com/something.html it is also redirecting that to tours/index.php?

How can I just redirect requests to /tours/index.php?tourid=x to /x  rather than everything?

Here is what I have now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /tours/?tourid=$1 [L]
```

I REALLY appreciate the replies. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply the rule to only files and folders which don't actually exist on the filesystem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /tours/?tourid=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will specifically target only the 'xxxxx.com/tours/index.php?tourid=x' URLs to /x, if you needed something else please comment.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/tours/index.php\?tourid=(.*)    /$1 [L]
```